# How much does a body weigh?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

My character is a cannibal, and he collects body parts of those he kills. I've been looking for some chart, or something that has the weight of the individual parts of the various sized creatures to give to my DM and know how to fill out my inventory. The system I am using is pathfinder.

Comment: Just use real-world analogs and common sense...

Comment: Must be hard for you to have your party members trust you when they sleep...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is real-world research, which we don't accept here. Real life biology questions like this can be asked elsewhere. If it isn't real world research, it's way too broad, given the sheer variety of creatures available. (Also it's really creepy levels of bookkeeping. That's not a close reason though.)

Comment: question: are you talking about humanoids, or other creature types? My VtC was cast when I first read it and was thinking about humanoids--because describing one as a cannibal means eating one's own species and characters are usually humanoids--but perhaps that buried assumption was false. If you're asking about weight distributions on fantastic monsters this *might* be on-topic? But if humanoid I stand by doppelgreener's comment and the closure.

Answer (score 17):

All the races have weight ranges, in addition to age and height ([Dwarf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf), [Elf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf) etc.). Work out how tall the body in question is, or take the average weight if you don't know the height, then divide the weight up: [This Kinesiology webpage](http://www.exrx.net/Kinesiology/Segments.html) provides percentages for humans, so it might need fudging for other races, but it provides some starting numbers to work with.

[This forum question](http://www.strangequestions.com/question/1108/What-percentage-of-weight-does-each-body-part-comprise-Head-arms-legs-torso.html) also provides percentages for body parts, but highlights that they can change over time, so the percentages aren't absolute; you may want to research more statistics and aggregate them for a more average set of data.

In case the above links disappear, some average-ish percentages, *Plagenhoef et al., 1983*:

```
Segment          Males   Females Average
Head             8.26    8.2     8.23
Whole Trunk      55.1    53.2    54.15
Thorax           20.1    17.02   18.56
Abdomen          13.06   12.24   12.65
Pelvis           13.66   15.96   14.81
Total Arm        5.7     4.97    5.335
Upper Arm        3.25    2.9     3.075
Forearm          1.87    1.57    1.72
Hand             0.65    0.5     0.575
Forearm & Hand   2.52    2.07    2.295
Total Leg        16.68   18.43   17.555
Thigh            10.5    11.75   11.125
Leg              4.75    5.35    5.05
Foot             1.43    1.33    1.38
Leg & Foot       6.18    6.68    6.43
```

I appreciate you might be looking for a more pathfinder-oriented chart for these statistics, but your question appears to cover quite a specific (and personally never before considered or seen) circumstance, and I think that there simply isn't that kind of consideration in any existing publication.

I'd really talk this over with your DM, in all honesty.

Answer (score 0):

**You can just look up the total weight in the *Races* section**

Along with whatever other things that a character receives before taking a class is their **possible height and weight**, which you roll ([see example here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf#TOC-Random-Height-and-Weight))

Just compare that to the overall percentage of meat that you harvested and you have its weight. **Though I agree with Ardavion with consulting your DM; this is his/her game, and this decision falls into their territory.**